# Is it safe to define a method that has the same name as the class in scala?

Tags: java, android, scala, guice

I am trying to introduce Scala into my Android project, which uses Guice for DI. For Guide to work, I need to add the `@Inject` annotation to the constructor I would like Guice to use. In my case I created a Scala class and I need to use it in my Java code.

```
scala:
class scalaClass1(a: String) {
   var myA = a

   @Inject
   def this() = { this("test") }
}
```

This looks alright, correct? But in another case the constructor does not have any parameters, so I tried

```
scala:
class scalaClass2() {
   var myA: String = null

   @Inject
   def this() = { this() }
}
```

And I got an syntax error. Something like recursive definition. Then I tried this:

```
scala:
class scalaClass2() {
   var myA: String = null

   @Inject
   def scalaClass2() = { this }
}
```

The code compiled and the app works well on my phone. I have no idea why. I browsed in google, but I could not find any definition/explanation about having a method that has the same name as the class. Why this works? Is there any better solution to my problem?

Comment: Are you trying to inject a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to to apply `@Inject` to a constructor without parameters you can use this:

```
class scalaClass2 @Inject () {
  // whatever
}
```

Note the mandatory empty parentheses. You need them to apply an annotation on the primary constructor. But in this particular case you don't even need `@Inject`; see below.

In your second example (when you define `def this() = { this() }`) you are getting an error because you can't define multiple constructors with the same signature, and that's exactly what you are doing - you define primary constructor without parameters and immediately you define secondary constructor, again without parameters.

And in the third example you're really defining a method named `scalaClass2` which returns `this`. It is perfectly valid, but it is not a constructor. As far as I remember, Guice does not need `@Inject` annotation on parameterless constructor when it is the only constructor in the class, so you can inject `scalaClass2` or ask it from Guice, who will create it for you. But you don't really need `scalaClass2` method; Guice may call it as a part of method injection procedure but it won't do anything.

Comment: Ah - didn't spot anywhere in the spec requiring the parentheses in order to apply the annotation. Thanks for that.

Comment: Yes, when I was toying with Guice a year ago it was also a surprise for me :) I'm sure I had asked a question on this then and I thought of adding a link to it, but I cannot find it now...

Comment: Thanks guys. Also I found a discussion at http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-Syntax-for-Annotations-on-Constructor-td2002238.html very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, according to convention class names should start with upper case and methods with lower. But if we would not follow them I would say it is not safe.

Consider having a companion object to the class with `apply` method defined.

```
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)
object Person {
  def apply(name: String, age: Int) = new Person(name, age) }
```

and then create a method with same name and list parameters:

```
def Person(lastName: String, score: Int): String = s"${lastName} got ${score} points in last game"
```

Now if you want to make use of object `apply` method you cannot do it in regular way:

```
Person("McKenzie", 1000)
```

will yield `McKenzie got 1000 points in last game`

Comment: I think the original poster didn't ask anything about `apply` method.

Comment: He did not but the question is about class name and method's name and it is pretty common to create companion objects which may cause problems. The question was 'is it safe?' No, it's not safe having same names.